# How to color a UISearchBar so that it looks seamless with the background

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to color this UISearchBar so that it looks seamless with the background (like in the second image). Is it possible to do this? I've tried setting in IB and programmatically but no luck.

thanks for any help

[image: UISearchBar screenshot]

Here's the desired look:

[image: UISearchBar screenshot - desired look]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   UITextField *searchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    [searchField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchfield_bg"]];

    [self.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    UIImage *searchimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_panel.png"];

    for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.frame];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:searchimg];
            [self.searchBar insertSubview:bg aboveSubview:subview];
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            [bg release];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Im using these images, you can use your and change the color too, my requirements were to make a black searchbar so im using black color

[image]
[image]

and it will look like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

just setTint color like this..

```
    [searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.81 green:.14 blue:.19 alpha:1]];//set alpha with your requirement
```

also with image use this code its working great..

```
   for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.frame];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bar.png"]];
            [searchBar insertSubview:bg aboveSubview:subview];
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
```

And for whole search bar with Red color then simple copy paste this code mate.. here i solve this problem

```
    for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.frame];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [searchBar insertSubview:bg aboveSubview:subview];
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
    [searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: I've tried that but for me it just displays with a glossed over pinkish hue.

Comment: please, if you have time :)

Comment: @hanumanDev see [searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: see this new try this with .81 .14 and .19

Comment: thanks, but the searchBar still displays with very light pink. strange

Comment: just change the value of red to 1 and any other values to zero after that its display in red color mate ..

Comment: @hanumanDev i got solution mate.. at last i see every backcolor and titnt color are red... enjoy the coding mate.. jay hanuman.. :)